# Django rest swagger 'get' response model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger-2.0

I am using `django-rest-framework==3.5.3` `and django-rest-swagger==2.1.0`. How can i have response model in present in swagger UI.

Here http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/findPetsByStatus in get methods we can see response model.

In my case, there is only HTTP Status Code.

[image]Is there a way to achieve it in django-rest-swagger?

---edit

I am using class based views. And the model is showing on put, post, patch methods.

Comment: When you click in try it out, I think you can see it in the body response. But I'm not sure if I understood your question.

Comment: Yes you can. But i wanted to see it the same way as in post description (without using try it out)

Comment: @Quba, Hello, did you find a solution to fill this info?

Comment: @Oleksandr Dashkov No, unfortunately